# How to create a job, when job_action need to call a procedure having CLOB parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jobs, job-scheduling

I have a procedure which is being called at server side and I need to make it asynchronous.

So I have created another proc in which I'll create Oracle'Job and this will call that proc in its job_action.
Proc is:

```
  PROCEDURE upload_csv_file_data(a_what_to_do IN VARCHAR2,
                             a_logon_user IN VARCHAR2,
                             a_csv_data IN CLOB)
  IS
    v_job_action  VARCHAR2(32676);
    /*v_log_error   VARCHAR2(32676);*/
    v_job_name    VARCHAR2(100);
  BEGIN

    v_job_action := 'process_csv_file_data(''' || a_what_to_do || ''',''' || a_logon_user || ''',' || a_csv_data || ');';
    v_job_name    := 'UPLOAD_CSV_FILE_DATA';



    sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(
        job_name => v_job_name,
        job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action => 'begin ' || v_job_action || ' EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; end;',
        start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,
        job_class => 'BATCH_CLASS',
        comments => 'Start uplaoding CSV file data.',
        auto_drop => TRUE,
        enabled => TRUE);

  END;
```

Proc which needs to be called IN JOB is:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE process_csv_file_data(a_what_to_do IN VARCHAR2,
                                 a_logon_user IN VARCHAR2,
                                 a_csv_data IN CLOB)
    IS
    .
       /*STEPS*/
    .
    END;
```

But since one of the passing parameters for this PROC is CLOB hence whenever I'm trying to call is PROC using in JOB it throws an error "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error".

As job_action datatype is of VARCHAR2(4000); and hence the moment CLOB datatype is dynamically passed while calling the proc in the Job action it throws an error "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error"

Kindly suggest on this.
(can we pass the parameters using bind variables?)

Answer (score 0):

The CLOB data has to come from somewhere. Instead of passing it as a parameter to the procedure you should stash it in a table which the job can read. Alternatively could you read the original source as a file, ideally as an external table, or as a BFILE.

Answer (score 0):

`SYSTIMESTAMP` returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value, so  `FROM_TZ(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'US/Eastern')` is useless and it actually should return an error.

Data type of `job_action` is `VARCHAR2`, i.e. up to 32K characters, so `CLOB` is not possible.

Like APC I recommend a BFILE or an external table for processing.